# How to combine multiple Line Graphs together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to using R so please bear with me as my code might not look the best. So I want to combine multiple line graphs together since right now I have written code for each item that I am analyzing. This is the dataset I am using: https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2020/2020-09-01/readme.md

I am looking at only the USA and the cereal crops (like Wheat, Rice, Maize, and Barley) and I created a line graph to show how much of each has been grown in the USA from the year 2000-2018. Please refer to my code below:

```
##Wheat
line_interactive_1 <- key_crop_yields %>%
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%
  filter(Code == "USA" & `Wheat (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  select(Year, Code, `Wheat (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  head(19) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Wheat (tonnes per hectare)`)) +
  geom_line(color = "green") +
  labs(title = "Wheat (tonnes per hectare) Grown in USA From 2000-2018")

ggplotly(line_interactive_1)


##Rice
line_interactive_2 <- key_crop_yields %>%
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%
  filter(Code == "USA" & `Rice (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  select(Year, Code, `Rice (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  head(19) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Rice (tonnes per hectare)`)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Rice (tonnes per hectare) Grown in USA From 2000-2018")


ggplotly(line_interactive_2)


##Maize
line_interactive_3 <- key_crop_yields %>%
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%
  filter(Code == "USA" & `Maize (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  select(Year, Code, `Maize (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  head(19) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Maize (tonnes per hectare)`)) +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Maize (tonnes per hectare) Grown in USA From 2000-2018")

ggplotly(line_interactive_3)


##Barley
line_interactive_4 <- key_crop_yields %>%
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%
  filter(Code == "USA" & `Barley (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  select(Year, Code, `Barley (tonnes per hectare)`) %>%
  head(19) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = `Barley (tonnes per hectare)`)) +
  geom_line(color = "orange") +
  labs(title = "Barley (tonnes per hectare) Grown in USA From 2000-2018")

ggplotly(line_interactive_4)
```

Ideally, I would like all of those in 1 graph. I was thinking of maybe creating a matrix of only the columns Code, Year, Wheat, Rice, Maize, and Barley - but wasn't sure how to go about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you build the desired matrix using `facet_wrap()` after selecting the desired variables. The interactive elements from `plotly` are kept in `ggplot2` objects. So it is more practical transforming your data to long after choosing the variables. Then, sketch the plot using facets and finally transform to `plotly` interface. Here the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
#Data
Plot <-  key_crop_yields %>%
  filter(Code=="USA") %>%
  select(c(Year,Code,`Wheat (tonnes per hectare)`,`Rice (tonnes per hectare)`,
         `Maize (tonnes per hectare)`,`Barley (tonnes per hectare)`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year,Code)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value,color=name,group=name)) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_y')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('orange','red','blue','green'))
#Transform
ggplotly(Plot)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so helpful to learn how to combine multiple graphs. If I may ask you, what does the `pivot_longer(-c(Year,Code))` do?

Comment: @Mars Sure, that piece of code keeps the variables Year and Code for each of the remaining variables. In other words, it is like you take each column and only have Year,Code,Var1,...,Year,Code,Varn and it combines all this mini dataframes in only one structure. Let me know if that was clear enough for you!

Comment: Hi, sorry - super random! I was looking back at the code and I was wondering what exactly does the `facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y')` do?